# How to manipulate the DOM to utilize the MVVM pattern, I want to implement this snippet using Knockout's click binding

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

How to manipulate the DOM to utilize the MVVM pattern, I want to implement this snippet using Knockout's click binding. I don't want to use jQuery nor JavaScript DOM methods. I am taking help from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

```js
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    document.getElementById('search-me').addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.geoAddr(geocoder, map);
    });
}
```

```html
<input class="text-box" id="location" type="text" value="Delhi, India">
<button class="my-button" id="search-me" type="submit">
        <img class="search-img" src="image/mybutton.png" alt="search" />
</button>
```

Comment: What in the documentation do you find trouble with?

Comment: @gkb i am willing that Data manipulation of the DOM must must utilize the MVVM pattern, but not by using jQuery nor Javascript DOM methods.
I want to Implement this feature using Knockout's click binding  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html on above js code.

Comment: do you want to call `self.geoAddr(geocoder, map);` on the click of the button through knockout's `click` binding?

Comment: @gkb No. document.getElementById('search-me').addEventListener('click', function() this one!

Comment: assuming the `button` is not being created on the fly, you can simply use `<button class="my-button" id="search-me" type="submit" data-bind="click: handlerForTheClickEvent">` to attach a `click` event handler to the button.

Comment: @gkb i want that search me should be clicked using knockout click binding function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure exactly what you are after but something like

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.location = ko.observable('Delhi, India');
  this.geoAddr = function() {
    var location = self.location();
    alert('my location is ' + location);
  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="location">Location:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" data-bind="textInput: location" />
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Search" data-bind="click: geoAddr">
```